# R: plot : variable title font size

Tags: r, plot

I have a plot and have a chart title: A B C
I would like the A to be small, B to be medium and C to be large.
I tried:

```
plot(1:10,main=paste("A","B","C"),cex.main=c(0.5,1,1.5))
```

but this gives an error.

I would be grateful for your help in correcting the above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cex.main only excepts one single value. But a possible solution would be mtext() instead of using the main parameter:

```
plot(1:10)
mtext(c("A","B","C"), 3, line=1.5, cex = c(1,2,3), at = c(4,5,6))
```

You can change the y position by adjusting the "line"-value and the x-position by adjusting "at".